# How can I use existing EFI partition when installing Arch

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, disk, gpt

I'm trying to install Arch Linux for the first time - I used the following video to learn how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxTTp7gDRn4

In the video, the person explains how to do it in an empty SSD, but in my case I'm using Windows and I already have an EFI partition:

[image]

I'm not sure how I can mount the partition. If I understood correctly, I should:

```
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot
```

Is that correct? Is there any risk of wiping up what I already have there? Something that I'm a bit confused is: the EFI partition is empty accordingly to the Disk Management (see picture). If it's empty, why the hell do I have that? This notebook is brand new.

Comment: It's not empty. It just contains a handful of very small files with a lot of room for more. This is SOP and is mostly about future-proofing the EFI standard. The mount command you show would work for accessing it... though the EFI partition and the linux boot folder/partition are not quite the same thing. the EFI partition is normaly mounted as `/boot/efi`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are supposed to chroot to the hard drive and then mount it using `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/EFI`.

If you want to use the existing EFI partition, this link might help you out: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition#Check_for_an_existing_partition

Comment: Did you already finalize your arch installation, and burn it to your hard drive?